# Conditional result type in WCF

Tags: c#, json, rest, wcf, object

Is possible returning 2 different types addicted on condition?

for example:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "GET",
    UriTemplate = "/GetMyResult",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
    )]
object GetMyResult(int x);
```

and function declaration:

```
public object GetMyResult(string x)
{
    if (x)
      return new UserEntity () {...} // some object with properties
    else
      return new MessageErr() {...} // object with 2 properties Text and error code
}
```

This code do not work for me. Is some good practice how can I do that ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't return `object` in `WCF` because `service` is meant to clearly describe what it `needs` and what it will `return`.

But there is another way by which you can do this which i have implemented in my project which is similar as your needs.

You can make a `class` with a `property` where you will send the `object`.

```
public class CustomResponse
{
  public CustomData Data { get; set; }
}

[KnownType(typeof(UserEntity))]
[KnownType(typeof(MessageErr))]
[DataContract]
public class CustomData
{
  [DataMember]
  public object Data { get; set; }

  public CustomData(object obj) 
  {
     this.Data = obj;
  }
}
```

And here is how you will call it

```
CustomResponse Response = new CustomResponse();
UserEntity obj = new UserEntity();
Response.Data = new CustomData(obj);
```